# Express CORS Works On Others Endpoints But One

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have a simple Express project as my API endpoint using cors as middleware.

The cors works on any others endpoint but one. Here is my code snapshot:

```
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/shuttles',
    tokenPassport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
        // ....
        // implementation goes here...
        // ....
})

app.get('/deposit',
    tokenPassport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
        // ....
        // implementation goes here...
        // ....
})
```

The CORS in `/deposit` is working but not with `/shuttles`.

NB: Nevermind the `tokenPassport` require. It is for authorization.

**EDIT**

Here is the snapshot of network tab in chrome devtool. It's only send `OPTIONS` request and that is the response header. No `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53475102/edit to edit/update your question and add the exact error message that your browser is logging in the devtools console when you make a request to the '/shuttles' endpoint. Also, add a code snippet showing the frontend JavaScript code you’re using to make the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some meditation finding the solution in the universe, my Express application is hosted in Google App Engine and I realized that my `dispatch.yaml` contains

```
- url: "*/shuttles*"
  service: shuttle
```

It is the source of the problem.
Just rework the shuttle service and the routing then it solved :D

Thanks for all your comment, they all right.

Answer (score 2):

you can create your own middleware, in your `app.js` or `server.js` file.

```
//CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

if you want to use the `cros` module

```
const corsOptions = {
    "origin": "*",
    "methods": "GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE",
    // other options
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work :(
the cors still doesn't work on `shuttles` endpoint but works on other endpoints.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for that particular route, can you try explicitly adding `cors` this route. something like this `app.get('/shuttles', cors(corsOptions), other parameters`.

Comment: Have you see my edit on the question? I attach a snapshot of chrome devtool, any clue from that?

Comment: I can only see that the header is not there, you will have to do some debugging on your end, have you tried explicit passing of `cors`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you try adding this line in the express server 
`app.options('*', cors());` . also can you check whether from the client application when you are invoking the `/shuttles` end point are you adding 'access-control-origins' header to `*`

Comment: thank you for your reply, but unfortunately it doesn't work on any endpoints :(